# configure wamp server on Windows Server?

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, wamp, installation

I've been working with wampserver severl times and I've developed some proyects. These proyect work perfectly at localhost. But Now I have a Server with a Public IP.

I alredy installed wamp server but my question is, How can I configure wampserver in this server to allow remote conections to mysql and apache.

I tried editing http.conf to allow from All but it doesn't seem to be enough. I'm really new working with this kind of stuff. I'll thank any help.

Comment: Have you `Port Forwarded` your router so that it lets traffic into your network on port 80 and directs it to the ip address of the PC running WAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things you can try to diagnose the problem.

- Check if `Listen` directive is set to `80` and not `127.0.0.1:80`.
- Also check your `VirtualHost` directive to see if it allows connections from your public IP or not.
- Check your firewall software if it is blocking incoming connection.